# Проблемы новичка vue

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Пытаюсь воспроизвести код из документации [image: введите сюда описание изображения] vue в своем редакторе кода

```js
 const EventHandling = {
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Привет, Vue.js!'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      reverseMessage() {
        this.message = this.message
            .split('')
            .reverse()
            .join('')
      }
    }
  }
  Vue.createApp(EventHandling).mount('#event-handling')
```

```html
<div id="event-handling">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Перевернуть сообщение</button>
</div>
```

Однако данный код работает только в CodePen.
Опечаток быть не должно, по итогу я просто копировал код с сайта.
Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, но лучше начать с начала... Вы подключаете исходный код Vue? Через cdn?

Comment: vue установлен через npm install vue.

Comment: npm run build или npm run dev запускали?